# How I can use svn from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have just installed `Eclipse 3.7 Indigo`. What should I use for svn?

Comment: You should try googling first, before posting on SO

Comment: @RMT He's a big user, he knows that ;)

Comment: how does not being a java developer mean u can't use google?

Comment: Try googling Installing SVN with Eclipse you'll get your answer

Comment: @BigUser: Sorry no offense ;) It's just that if you enter "Eclipse svn" into google you get the right page as result #1. People here at SO love make a little fun. BTW welcome to SO!

Comment: @Das_weezul good first impression eh?

Comment: @RMT: We may be a bunch of anti-social haters, but at least we are the nicest bunch of anti-social haters there is ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is the svn plugin for eclipse that you need to install.

Download & install instruction can be found [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=6D7997E5D22FA84AD7C5F443E6A7F06A?pageID=p4wYuA).

Answer (score 5):

Try installing [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can either use Subversive or Subclipse. Just install it through Help -> Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

http://aaronbonner.tumblr.com/post/6793073974/two-essential-update-sites-for-eclipse-indigo

try with tigris.